# draw a line above a image(picture)problem

Tags: iphone, line, quartz-2d

I am new to iphone development and can use the `quartz2D` using the code below to draw a line.
I want to realize the function that draws a line above a picture (image), for example I have a map image the name is: `map.jpg` (using the imageview to add).

Can you tell me the detailed code or method? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to draw a line.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 { 

      mouseSwiped = NO;

      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 

      if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {

            drawImage.image = nil;

            return;

      } 

      lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

      lastPoint.y -= 20; 

} 

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
 {

      mouseSwiped = YES; 

      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 

      CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

      currentPoint.y -= 20; 


      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

      [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

      CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

      CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);

      CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 0, 0, 1);

      CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

      CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);

      CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

      CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

      drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

      UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

      lastPoint = currentPoint; 

      mouseMoved++; 

      if (mouseMoved == 10) {

            mouseMoved = 0;

      } 

}
```

Comment: I really thanks for your code.  I want to use the method to realize the function(- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect ) that draw a line above a picture(image). 
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
 CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
 CGFloat components[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
 CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
 CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50, 50);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 200);
 CGContextStrokePath(context);
 CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
 CGColorRelease(color);